# Can't reach public IP or domain name of my server from within

Tags: nginx, networking, port, ubuntu-20.04

Say I have a domain name "my.domain.com" with an A Record that resolves to the public IPv4 address (say 160.200.200.21) of my server (running Ubuntu 20.04)

I've installed BigBlueButton on the server  and almost everything is fine except that BigBlueButton needs to be able to reach itself from the domain name or public IP and there it fails and gives this error:

```
curl: (28) Failed to connect to  port 443: Connection timed out
# Error: Could not connect to the configured hostname/IP address
```

So i have done the following checks:

- Used `netcat -l` on port 80 and 443 with a remote server to make sure the ports are opened => SUCCESS

also the following commands i ran:

```
~# curl https://my.domain.com 
curl: (28) Failed to connect to my.domain.com port 443: Connection timed out

~# curl my.domain.com 
curl: (28) Failed to connect to my.domain.com port 80: Connection timed out

~# wget https://my.domain.com 
--2023-11-07 20:08:51--  https://my.domain.com/
Resolving my.domain.com (my.domain.com)... 160.200.200.21
Connecting to my.domain.com (my.domain.com)|160.200.200.21|:443... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.
```

But `curl http://google.com` responds!

Also note that the commands above work perfectly from another server or computer

```
~# netstat -anltp | grep :80
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4082/nginx: master
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:52562         127.0.0.1:8021          ESTABLISHED 13903/node
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      4082/nginx: master
tcp6       0      0 :::8021                 :::*                    LISTEN      13262/freeswitch
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8090          :::*                    LISTEN      13076/java
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:32800         127.0.0.1:8021          ESTABLISHED 13745/java
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8021          127.0.0.1:32800         ESTABLISHED 13262/freeswitch
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8021          127.0.0.1:52562         ESTABLISHED 13262/freeswitch


~# netstat -anltp | grep :443
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      12628/haproxy
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      12628/haproxy
```

At this point I don't know what to check again or where to look for the problem.
This server is a virtual machine, provided by a provider so i only have ssh and root access
provider said it was behind a firewall, but since the ports are clearly opened I don't know if they can be blamed.

So what is happening is my.domain.com is perfectly reachable outside the server(on browser or CLI) but not within the server even though the relevant ports are opened.

one thing I found weird, maybe the info will be useful: when I did `netcat -l 80` on my server it worked even though Nginx was running on port 80. `netcat -l 443` failed saying port is in use, i had to first shutdown the process using it before i could run the test.

Comment: This is almost certainly a NAT hairpinning issue in your router - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#:~:text=NAT%20hairpinning%2C%20also%20known%20as,appropriate%20machine%20on%20the%20LAN).

Comment: If that is all you need, why not just the external IP address as a secondary to the server?

Comment: @Bib The IP is already set on the firewall which i don't have access to or control

Comment: @joeqwerty thanks for pointing this out, unfortunatly the Admins are not willing to do anything about it, but i found and alternative i'll post the answer!

Comment: It does not matter if the IP address has been assigned to the firewall, you can still set it at the host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your VM cannot reach itself through an external connection, you can modify /etc/hosts to map one of the net adapter IP addresses (even localhost) to the DNS name of the machine. These configurations take precedence over the ones in external DNS.

```
127.0.0.1 my.domain.com
```

Comment: Ok that seems to solve the issue, but not completely as I mentionned i'm installing BigBlueButton and in the docs they require me to edit the hosts file and put my public ip address with my domain name (in case i'm behind a firewall which is my case) so changing the public ip to local host makes my tests work, but not BigBlueButton, looks like i can't have both ^^'

Comment: It Finally worked with the LAN ip adress, instead of 127.0.0.1 I entered the lan IP and it all worked! thank you for pointing me in the right direction!